# Resolving invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system

Here is my code kindly tell me how to resolve this error. both functions are methods of the class.

```
    void* make_desc(void* arg){


        int *k;
        k = (int *) arg;

        Node* tt;
        int i,j;


        //for(int k=0;k<4;k++){
        int c[16],t[2];
        //tr is in the begin of the code, used for going, up,down,left or rigth
        i=this->zero[0]+tr[(*k)].first;
        j=this->zero[1]+tr[(*k)].second;
        if(i>=0 && i<4 && j>=0 && j<4){

            cp(this->array,c);
            c[this->zero[0]*4+this->zero[1]]=c[i*4+j];

            c[i*4+j]=0;
            t[0]=i;
            t[1]=j;

            //check if note already seen, if not seen add
            //if seen but depth is smaller than previous, add also
            if(setx.find(myhash(c))==setx.end()){
                Node *tt = new Node(c,t,this->depth+1,this->path);
                //l.push_back(tt);
            }
            else if(setx[myhash(c)]>this->depth+1){
                setx[myhash(c)]=this->depth+1;
                Node *tt = new Node(c,t,this->depth+1,this->path);
                //l.push_back(tt);
            }
        }

        pthread_exit(tt);
        //return tt;

        //      return l;
//    }
    }




    vector<Node*> threads(){

        vector<Node*> l;
        Node* ret;
        int j=0;

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            j=i;
            pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,make_desc,(void*)&j);

        }
```

//ERROR

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void Node::Make_threads()’:
    main.cpp:208:54: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void* Node::make_desc(void*)’
                 pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,make_desc,NULL);
                                                          ^
    main.cpp:169:11: note: declared here
         void* make_desc(void* arg) {
               ^~~~~~~~~
    main.cpp: In function ‘bool A_star_Manhattan()’:
    main.cpp:272:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘Node::make_desc()’
                 vector<Node *> dsc = current_node->make_desc();
                                                              ^
    main.cpp:169:11: note: candidate: void* Node::make_desc(void*)
         void* make_desc(void* arg) {
               ^~~~~~~~~
    main.cpp:169:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided***
```

Comment: Please use the title to communicate the specific problem, not talk about how you're having problems in general terms.

Comment: Note: This question has nothing to do with threads. It's a question about how to provide a pointer to a member function as an arg in a function call that wants a pointer to an ordinary function.

Comment: Also note: Calling the Posix threads library (pthreads) from a new C++ program is a bad idea. You should be using the [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) class instead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Answer (score 0):

Using the `pthread` library, the argument function can not be a member of a class.
You have to define it separately outside everything.

```
argument of type "void *(myclass::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *(*)(void *)"C/C++(167)
```

As I can see, you are using **C++**, and I highly recommend you to check C++ multithreading.  [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)
The syntax is much simpler, and everything is implemented using `pthread` behind the scenes.